# "no space left on device" even after removing all containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

While experimenting with Docker and Docker Compose I suddenly ran into "no space left on device" errors. I've tried to remove everything using methods suggested in similar questions, but to no avail.

Things I ran:

```
$ docker-compose rm -v

$ docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)

$ docker rmi $(docker images | grep "^<none>" | awk "{print $3}")

$ docker system prune

$ docker container prune

$ docker rm $(docker stop -t=1 $(docker ps -q))

$ docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
```

As far as I'm aware there really shouldn't be anything left now. And it looks that way:

```
$ docker images    
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

Same for volumes:

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
```

And for containers:

```
$ docker container ls   
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Unfortunately, I still get errors like this one:

```
$ docker-compose up
Pulling adminer (adminer:latest)...
latest: Pulling from library/adminer
90f4dba627d6: Pulling fs layer
19ae35d04742: Pulling fs layer
6d34c9ec1436: Download complete
729ea35b870d: Waiting
bb4802913059: Waiting
51f40f34172f: Waiting
8c152ed10b66: Waiting
8578cddcaa07: Waiting
e68a921e4706: Waiting
c88c5cb37765: Waiting
7e3078f18512: Waiting
42c465c756f0: Waiting
0236c7f70fcb: Waiting
6c063322fbb8: Waiting
ERROR: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob865563210: no space left on device
```

Some data about my Docker installation:

```
$ docker info
Containers: 0
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 17.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Dirs: 15
Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
Volume: local
Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 6e23458c129b551d5c9871e5174f6b1b7f6d1170
runc version: 810190ceaa507aa2727d7ae6f4790c76ec150bd2
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
apparmor
seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.10.0-32-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.685GiB
Name: engelbert
ID: UO4E:FFNC:2V25:PNAA:S23T:7WBT:XLY7:O3KU:VBNV:WBSB:G4RS:SNBH
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

And my disk info:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           787M   10M  778M   2% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3   33G   25G  6,3G  80% /
tmpfs           3,9G   46M  3,8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       81M   81M     0 100% /snap/core/2462
/dev/loop1       80M   80M     0 100% /snap/core/2312
/dev/nvme0n1p1  596M   51M  546M   9% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p5  184G   52G  123G  30% /home
tmpfs           787M   12K  787M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           787M   24K  787M   1% /run/user/1000
```

And:

```
$ df -hi /var/lib/docker
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p3   2,1M  2,0M   68K   97% /
```

As said, I'm still experimenting, so I'm not sure if I've posted all relevant info - let me know if you need more.

Anyone any idea what more could be the issue?

Comment: Post the the output of `df -h` in your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani Done!

Comment: Are you running this on VM, which OS?

Comment: @TarunLalwani No VM, directly on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS installation.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `df -h /var/lib/docker`

Comment: @RobBlake Added.

Comment: Does it run out of space straight-away or are there multiple containers running before the image is pulled?

Comment: The first one, I think, but I also got such errors when the images had already been downloaded but I was trying to start my app.

Comment: @RobBlake It stops more immediately when running it now: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25368374/ (database is the name of my... image?)

Comment: What does `df -i /var/lib/docker` show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152507/discussion-between-rob-blake-and-vincent).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is that `/var/lib/docker` is on the `/` filesystem, which is running out of inodes. You can check this by running `df -i /var/lib/docker`

Since `/home`'s filesystem has sufficient inodes and disk space, moving Docker's working directory there there should get it going again.

(Note that the this assumes there is nothing valuable in the current Docker install.)

First stop the Docker daemon. On Ubuntu, run

```
sudo service docker stop
```

Then move the old `/var/lib/docker` out of the way:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker~
```

Now create a directory on `/home`:

```
sudo mkdir /home/docker
```

and set the required permissions:

```
sudo chmod 0711 /home/docker
```

Link the `/var/lib/docker` directory to the new working directory:

```
sudo ln -s /home/docker /var/lib/docker
```

Then restart the Docker daemon:

```
sudo service docker start
```

Then it should work again.

Comment: As discussed in chat, that was it :) Thank you so much!

Comment: This did not work for me. I somehow did not have a /var/lib/docker directory... tried creating it and setting the permisisons listed above... still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, if you have removed all the containers you can also try `docker system prune` which will remove dangling images, containers and anything else.

Answer (score 1):

This may not directly answer the question but it can be useful in general if the Dockerfile used to create the image is available.

Make sure in particular to limit the number of layers that will be generated, hence, when writing the Dockerfile, avoid doing this:

```
RUN apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y package1 
RUN apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y package2 
RUN apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y package3
```

and do this instead:

```
RUN apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y \
    package1 \
    package2 \
    package3
```

Doing so drastically reduced the size of the image as well as the inode usage, since less layers are generated. This helped address the issue in my case (where the inodes would all get used up).

Make sure to remove the potential intermediate image that was generated by the failed build to free up space `docker rmi <IMAGE_ID>`.

For more tips, you can check out this site about [Optimizing Docker images](https://linuxhint.com/optimizing-docker-images/).